# Format of CSV file content in Unix mail body is not proper

Tags: csv, unix, mailx

I’m facing a format issue in sending .csv file content in unix email body. When i do cat filename.csv it appears proper format but when sending the same csv file content in email body columns length are overlapping with before columns length

```
sqlplus username/pwddbname<<EOF
Set feedback off;
Set linesize 32767;
Set pagesize 1000;
Set wrap off;
Spool filename.csv;
Column name format a10;
Column initdate format a10;
Column lastdate format a10;
Select name,initdate,lastdate,amout from table;
Spool off;
EOF;

mailx -s “subject” receiver@mail.com < filename.csv
```

Output looks like

```
Name      Initdate   lastdate    Amount
———————- ————————- ———————- ———————-
John mill 11/12/2019 12/12/2019    10
Tim   11/12/2019 12/12/2019    20
Sam   11/12/2019 12/12/2019    49
Rich kin 11/12/2019 12/12/2019    10
```

In 2nd, 3rd and 4th rows, column2 overlapped in 1st column. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there carriage returns in the file?

Comment: No carriage returns

Comment: Your format is not CSV (comma separated values) but probably fixed width columns. Did you copy&paste the output? Or could it be the result of your mail user agent using a proportional font instead of a fixed width font? I suggest to send the file as an attachment, not in the mail body. Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification.

Comment: I did copy paste of the output from email body. I cannot send it as attachment as the requirement is to send output in email body.

Answer (score 0):

To export to CSV use those settings in `sqlplus`:

```
set colsep ,
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
```

Of course you can change the delimiter

Comment: Used trimspool on and pagesize 0 but no use. I may not use comma(,) separator as wanted the output in email like a tabular look.

Comment: @Nani, so do not name it CSV. You can use tabular format, how you will calculate the number of tabs (if need more than one)? Maybe will be better to send as attach.